# Many queires with FetchMode.SUBSELECT

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to use @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) on OneToMany mapped set collection. But when I run a test program it still generates many queries. What could be the reason?

Thanks and Regards
 Aravind

Answer (score 0):

With “subselect” enabled, it will create two select statements.

1. Select statement to retrieve all the Stock records.
2. Select all its related collections in a sub select query.

Please put your code here to see what are u doing :)